# iptables rules dissappear when manually adding a nat rule to iptables-persistent file

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, fail2ban

I noticed that about two-thirds of the rules I have specified in `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` stopped showing in `sudo iptables -S` after I added a `nat` rule. (I isolated the disappearance to adding this one rule.) I have fail2ban and iptables-persistent installed. Where are my iptables rules going?

**`/etc/iptables/rules.v4`**

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sat Feb 10 14:34:17 2018
*filter
:INPUT DROP [1858:197791]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2564:302408]
-A INPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dports 22:23 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dports 50000:50999 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --match multiport --dports 120:121 -s 999.999.999.999 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 122 -s 999.999.999.999 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 123 -s 999.999.999.999 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i veth0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o veth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Feb 10 14:34:17 2018
```

**`sudo iptables -S`**

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N f2b-sshd
-N f2b-vsftpd-iptables
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 23 -j f2b-vsftpd-iptables
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
-A f2b-vsftpd-iptables -j RETURN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have ':INPUT DROP' in rules.v4 and '-P INPUT ACCEPT' in `sudo iptables -S` output. Looks too much different, like You forget to reconfigure iptables-persistent package after rules changes.

Reconfiguring of **iptables-persistent** is necessary after every change of rules via the command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure iptables-persistent
```

I suggest three steps:
1). Clear rules.

```
# delete all current rules and user chains
iptables -F
iptables -X

# global policy (target by default)
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

# localhost
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

2). Define Your rules again.
3). Reconfigure iptables-persistent.

Comment: Will I lose my SSH connection when I delete the current rules?

Comment: After deleting rules and setting global policy for input and output chains to ACCEPT - connection will stay. Certainly, be careful, when You will define rules again. If Your server does not support rescue mode for such cases  - I recommend to add to "cron" small script which will be clear all rules every hour - this will help You if rules block access for yourself.

Comment: Reconfiguring showed the problem. I was adding the last rule under the filter table instead of letting iptables-persistent write a new set of rules for the nat table.

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure iptables-persistent` - run every time after changes in iptables rules. And Your rules will be in actual state after every system reboot.